# EF DbContext registered with ServiceStack's Funq is disposed when running unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, servicestack, dbcontext

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses ServiceStack and EF. In my AppHost I configure Funq to default to Request reuse scope:

```
container.DefaultReuse = ReuseScope.Request;
```

Then I register my EF context.

When running unit tests (i.e. when no HTTP request exists) I get the "DbContext disposed" exception. I assume it's because my context is immediately disposed by Funq in the absence of the HTTP request. Right?

I have previous experience with StructureMap that supports a hybrid reuse (i.e. either per-request if HTTP context exists or per-thread), so how would I configure Func to do the same for me?

Answer (score 1):

My bad! Turns out this is not Funq's issue but that of the EF database migrations:

Apparently migrations logic cleans up after itself by disposing of the context. My problem was that I used `IDbContextFactory` to provide the context to migrations, and inside its `Create` method I was returning the instance of the context resolved by Funq's container. Which is how the instance in the container ended up disposed after migrations was done with it.